# Add the URL to a site recommendation question from Meta SE about Wordpress to [wordpress] tag excerpt

Tags: discussion, tags, migration

Tl;Dr: Is it OK to add the url to [Where should I ask WordPress questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18941/289691) (Question from Meta SE) to the [wordpress](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag excerpt?

The reason is that while some questions about Worpress might be on topic in Web Applications SE most questions eventually are deleted.

---

Few moments ago I found a question migrated from Super User to Web Applications three months ago because it was bumped due to edits done by a couple of users that made some improvements. Unfortunatelly this question is off-topic in Web Applications. I'm not complaining, so I will not enter into the details of this specific case in this post, just sharing what bring to take a look to the tag excerpt of [wordpress](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wordpress):

> Popular blogging engine – mostly considered off-topic. Questions about wordpress.com belong on WebApps.SE. Questions about installing and maintaining WordPress belong on WordPress.SE

The tag wiki has no body.

There are several sites having a `[wordpress]` tagged questions were Worpress questions might be on-topic

- [Ask Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.stackexchange.com)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com)
- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com)
- [Wordpress Developement](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com)
- ...

see [[wordpress] is:question](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwordpress%5D%20is%3Aquestion) (Stack Exchange global search returns more than 200k results, from the above sites an others)

Here are two situations:

1. Regular users can only choose between a shortlist of site to migrate questions, so if the question might be more appropiate to another site the question should be flagged for moderator attention providing enough details about why the questions is appropiate for a site not included in the shortlist
2. There is a generalized misunderstanding about the Web Applications scope. Many people think that any question about webapps is on topic, but only questions about **using** them actually are. To make things more difficult

   1. many OP doesn't clear state enough details, but for some the question is still "answearable" / not as bad to be qualified as "crap"
   2. the separation between **using** a webapp and the other tasks have becoming blurry

I know that most users don't pay attention to tag wikis. Thinking specifically about people who vote to migrate and moderators, I'm wondering if it might be helpful to point them to one of the Meta Super User discussions about migration.

So far I have found these:

- [Reminder on voting to migrate](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9110/152004)
- [Do not migrate low-quality questions](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14896/152004)

The idea of pointing to a meta discussion from Meta SE instead of puting the information directly in the tag wiki is make it easier to mantain and to extend the solution to other tags that might have a similar situation according they being identified.

Using a discussion from Meta SE looks to be more appropiate as

1. the complete list of sites is in https://stackexchange.com/sites
2. there is a specialized tag for asking SE site recommentations `site-recommentions`,
3. there are questions asking about where to ask questions about wordpress and other related stuff asked previously that could be used as target to close as duplicate new question that already has an answer.

So the specific question is, is it OK to add the url to [Where should I ask WordPress questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18941/289691), a question from Meta SE instead of [Reminder on voting to migrate](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9110/152004), a questions from Meta Super User to the `wordpress` tag excerpt? Do you have a better suggestion?

Related

- [Questions about WordPress on Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/920/152004)
- [Possible to "protest" the transfer of a question to another forum?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1577/152004)
- [Add a migration path to Pro Web Masters from Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1595/152004)
- [Migrating high-quality, off-topic questions to another site in the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13937/152004)
- [Finding hard to fit into right site between Super User and Web Applications](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14924/152004)
- [Why do I have to go through a moderator to migrate my own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232006/289691)

---

Statistics

In Web Applications SE there are 77 % (391 / 511 )  deleted questions with `[wordpress]`.

Percentage of deleted questions tagged `[wordpress]` in Web Applications SE.

[image]

All the questions from 2021 were deleted.

All the questions from 2022 so far are in danger of being automatically deleted by Roomba.

Comment: Question about WordPress are absolutely out of scope on Super User. WordPress SE isn’t a selectable migration path for community users for questions. I personally just vote to close questions about WordPress that are submitted on SU.

Comment: Update: I just found [Where can I ask questions that aren't Super User questions?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/855/152004). Made an edit to update SE site names among other slight changes. This link might be included in the tag wiki body of [tag:wordpress] , I think.

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. There is nothing wrong with the current tag.

Comment: @DavidPostill Added some statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Tl;Dr: Please don't migrate [wordpress](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) questions to Web Applications.

---

It looks that this proposal will not get enough traction. That is fine.

Few days I posted this question, after digging in old discussions from Meta Web Applications about the site scope and tags of othe topics similar to "Wordpress" and thinking about the low participation in answering and curating posts in Web Applications, while this situation continues, as moderator of Web Applications kindly request to not migrate to this site questions that have [worpress](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/worpress) and don't include any other tag related to well known web applications (Gmail, Facebook, etc.), with the exception of web search engines and analytics as usually those questions are related to specialized tasks that are out of site scope.

The above becuse `[wordpress]` in Web Applications is a tag from the early days of this site, before the existence of [WordPress Developers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com). This tag is used for questions about Worpress, (WP or wordpress.org), the content managment software) which are off-topic. For questions about worpress.com, the website hosting service Web Applications have `[wordpress.com]`. While it might be look that retagging is a simple task, IMO it's better that users interested in asking a question about wordpress.com follow the guidance from the Ask Question form and the other customizable elements from Web Applications, rather than just arrive to the site through the migration path as that will not show the guidance about the workings of Web Applications.

NOTE: Not all the questions about worpress.com are on-topic in  Web Applications. I.E. paid account are able to do customizations that might fall out of the site scope. Also some questions related to SEO among other topics might be off-topic too.

To help users to learn about the workings of Web Applications, few days ago the homepage of Web Applications Help Center was updated, currently there is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) in Meta Web Applications to add a tag warning to `[wordpress]`. More changes are comming.

Related

- [How to choose a community?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12007/152004)
- [Guidance for new users about where to ask WordPress questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387480/289691)
- [What is the etiquette regarding asking a question again on another Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2086/152004)